Display suggestions based on user typing in search box
As user types in the username field, I want 3-4 pills showing up below the textbox of recommendations of usernames to choose from. How would I do this? I also have a websocket connection with backend, but just the UI snippet is fine.

I tried researching, but nothing so far.

Does this answer your question? Flutter TextField autocomplete overlay

How would I combine it with web_socket_channel library?

If you search for autocomplete, you can find many sample applications and packages, the logic is simple, it will show the username textfield information processed on the previously entered device, for this I leave 2 links here, you can get training and get detailed information by looking at these links heyflutter.com youtube channel autocomplate explanation.
and if you want, you can use the flutter_typeahead package available on pub.dev
